# Installing hudson slave agent as a service

Tags: windows-services, windows-8.1, hudson

I'd like to set up a Hudson slave agent (v3.2.2) as a Windows service on one of my Windows nodes (running Windows 8.1 x64 with .NET 3.5 installed). As of [this wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Hudson-ci/Installing_Hudson_Windows_Service#Install_Slave_as_a_Windows_service_.28requires_.Net_2_framework.29), there should be a *File > Install as Windows Service* menu option. But when I run the JNLP, there's no such option:

[image: Hudson JNLP UI]

So: How do I install the Hudson slave agent as a Windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug that has been submitted for this, Bug [427526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427526), and also a workaround. It is related to the version of Java. I used JDK 7u11 and I got the File option and was able to install the slave as a service.

Comment: I finally wrote a small C# service to wrap the Java process. Just out of curiosity: will switching back to Java 8 after having installed the service work with your solution?

Comment: Yes, it is working on the Windows 2008 slave I tried it on. I have other Windows slaves that have been running as a service for about 2 years that are still working with the new version of Hudson and Java 8.